# PostGIS and QGIS connection using queries?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I have a shapefile and a table which I import both of them to PostGIS. With pgAdminII I am able to manipulate the table, join to shapefile and calculate new fields. When I try to do that with python inside QGIS I get no success.

Example:

```
 uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
 uri.setConnection("localhost", "****", "****", "postgres", "postgres")
 uri.setDataSource("public", "shp_name","geom", '',"gid")

 db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
 db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
 db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
 db.setUserName(uri.username())
 db.setPassword(uri.password())
 db.open() 

query = db.exec_("""SELECT* INTO new_table FROM shp_name INNER JOIN table ON shp_name.code = table.code""")
query.next()
```

For example is I want to calculate the average of a column, I do that in pgAdminIII and it works but when I use it in python for QGIS it does nothing:

```
query1 = db.exec_("""SELECT avg(totdias) FROM sample_reside_join""")
query1.next()
```

I do that and it is not working. What I am doing wrong?
My objective is to perform some operations with tables and in final join to initial shapefile and open in QGIS, but I am not getting success.

Comment: can you expand on what "is not working"?

Comment: I can't see if the query is working, because when I open pgAdminII nothing is added. It is suposed to be like this? If I save in new_table, how do I find this new table?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.